# Artifactory, Maven and a project with several modules

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have a Maven project with several modules, with a structure similar to:

```
project
  module-1
    pom.xml
  module-2
    pom.xml
  ..
  module-N
    pom.xml
  pom.xml
```

I have defined the Artifactory Maven plugin in the parent `pom.xml` which is under `project`, like it is done in [the examples they offer on their website](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin#MavenArtifactoryPlugin-Configuration) and I've also tried [the example they have in git](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin#MavenArtifactoryPlugin-Configuration).

My problem is that I don't want to publish to Artifactory all the artifacts generated by the parent pom, but only those under certain modules, so I tried defining the plugin in the parent pom with the tag `<publishArtifacts>false</publishArtifacts>` and then defining the plugin again on the modules which contain artifacts I really do want to deploy with `<publishArtifacts>true</publishArtifacts>`, however no artifact is deployed.

If I try the other way, only specifying I do not want to publish Artifacts on the modules I don't, it does deploy all ignoring that configuration.

How should this be done using this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the publisher\excludePatterns in the artifactory plugin section of the pom.xml to exclude artifacts from being published.

you can declare multiple patterns with wildcards, and separate each with a comma.

For example, if you are using the sample from 
"https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/artifactory-maven-plugin-example"

then, setting you're pom with

```
<excludePatterns>multi3*.war,multi2*.jar</excludePatterns>
```

would exclude those files from being published to Artifactory.

hope that helps...

Comment: I think it should be `<excludePatterns>*multi3*.war,*multi2*.jar</excludePatterns>` since the deployment path is used to match patterns, not only the filename. Could you please modify your answer accordingly? I have created an issue with more details, asking JFrog to document that https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/issues/331.